# Java: Container with a key

Tags: java, oop

I have a class called Section and a class called Category the problem I currently have is that they both are containers.

They both contain ColouredMemoryBlocks (abstract class) but they themselves are a ColouredMemoryBlock which doesn't make sense to me, it is like saying an Array of Integer is an integer itself but also contains integers.

So I have something like

```
class Section extends ColouredMemoryBlock implements ColouredMemoryBlockContainer
class Category extends ColouredMemoryBlock implements ColouredMemoryBlockContainer
```

where the methods of these two are copy-pasted.

The advantage I have of having a Section and a Category being a ColouredMemoryBlock is that I can put them together in a List which contains ColouredMemoryBlocks.

ColouredMemoryBlock is like what Object is in Java for me.

Are there any alternatives to this? Does it make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  You can choose any class hierarchy you want, and design your classes that way.  What is not working for you?

Comment: I have to copy paste the methods of the Category class into the Section class whenever I make a change, they are identical apart from their types. What I need help on is the design of the hierarchy.

Comment: Being something and containing that same isn't necessarily nonsensical.  For example to represent any sort of graph, your Node is a "Node" and it contains a list of it's children.

Comment: What do you want these classes to do?  If all you need is to put them together in a list, you can simply make them all implement an empty interface, like `ColouredMemoryBlockContainer`, and if you create a `List` which contains that exact type, you'll be able to put them all in there.

Comment: Also a common design pattern is the Composite design pattern...

Comment: @RedDeckWins that's a good example.

Comment: ahh I wasn't aware of that, yes that's what I was looking for :) thanks! this is similar to what mjuarez is saying.